# Give a toggle button the color "#FF5D0000" in the main window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to give mij text on my button a customized color in the MainWindow.xaml.cs

Normally you give the color in the cs file by this way to the  command:

```
ToggleButton.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
```

But I want to give the hexnumber

I've already tried something like this :

```
SolidColorBrush Owncolor = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF5D0000"));
ToggleButton.Foreground = Brushes.Owncolor;
```

Comment: @TimRutter: That's a different colour.

Comment: But how did you get `Brushes.Owncolor` supported in your code? Did you tried that?

Comment: @stylus, I think that instead of `Brushes.Owncolor` you should simply write 
 `ToggleButton.Foreground = Owncolor;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing it in code behind (unless you have a very specific reason to do that), you can work on your xaml

```
<ToggleButton Foreground = "#FF5D0000"/>
```

if you are doing it based on some condition, also please take a look at [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/styles/trigger-datatrigger-event-trigger/). It's always a better practice to handle graphical stuff in your xaml as much as you can

for instance you can do

```
        <ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ToggleButton.Style>
        </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: yes, the reason is that I want to have green for the color of my pen if its pressed and the other color if its not pressed

<ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" Content="Log" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Margin="7,103,0,0" Height="33" RenderTransformOrigin="0.554,1.448" Background="#FF272626" Foreground="#FF5DF5EF" FontFamily="Calibri" Checked = "LButtonOn" Unchecked = "ButtonOff" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>

Comment: Then you can follow that tutorial to learn the basics of the triggers

Comment: @STYLUS Look at my answer. You can use any hexadecimal in xaml. Red and Green color are used as example. If you are using a viewmodel you can also use the DataTrigger, but i don't know your code. My answer is just to give you an idea

Answer (score 1):

Usually in WPF you tend to use styles defined in XAML to change how controls looks. However, using the `BrushConverter` works if you absolutely have to use the hexadecimal syntax in codebehind. I'd consider building a new `SolidColorBrush` with `Color.FromArgb` easier, but that also works.

As for how to use styles and XAML properly, you should probably read some tutorials or books. WPF is quite a different beast than Windows Forms or a lot of older UI frameworks, so there's some re-learning required.

The simplest way of achieving what you want (a different text colour when the button is pressed) would be the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF5D0000"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

When placed in the `Resources` of your `Window` it would apply to all `ToggleButton`s in that window.

Comment: And how can I do that?